# Difference between Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.ConversationID and EAS email2:ConversationId

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am trying to find a mapping of the ConversaionID I get from EWS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.conversationid(v=exchg.80).aspx) with the one I get from Exchange ActiveSync (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159339(v=exchg.80).aspx).

They do not seem to be same, the value I get from EWS has 80 characters and looks like a base64 string (example: AAQkADIwM2ZlM2ZlLWMwYjctNDg2Ny04MDU0LTVkMTFmM2IxY2ZjZQAQACkRMjewk3RHldv8l7aTV2s=) but the ConversationID I get from EAS is very short (example: 6RHD2wfukEuBKLIc9tSzkQ==)

How do I find a mapping of the Item.ConversationID in EAS?